# Using javascript to do a POST in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I'm using this plugin: [jquery-in-place-editor](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/), I'm trying to make a POST request according to the docs, but I'm not sure what URL to do the POST to, I can't seem to get it right.

If I'm in the `show` view for the object, which in this case the path is: `/quote_line_items/90`

But when the script executes I get this error: `No action responded to 90. Actions: create, destroy, edit, index, new, show, and update`

Which URL would I want to put in the scripts `url:` parameter?

**Update**

I just tried this.

```
$(".editable").editInPlace({
  url: "/quote_line_items/update",
  show_buttons: true
});
```

And I also tried:

```
$(".editable").editInPlace({
  url: "/quote_line_items/update/90",
  show_buttons: true
});
```

just to see what would happen, however, after the form is submitted it shows the `show` action for that page in an Iframe where the form was, which makes sense I suppose, like it did a GET request or something.

Comment: I'd assume that it's /quote_line_items/update/90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do a post with _method as a parameter having the value update that is if you are doing [restful routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html).

Otherwise I would point to /quote_line_items/update with a post.

Comment: I tried this, I dont think that makes sense, like as a URL param? so it'd be `/quote_line_items/update/90?_method=post

Comment: meh, I switched to a different plugin, issue was my nested attrs from within that model. Switching fixed it, but you helped the most.. so uh.. you get a win in the books.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you moved on, but I do have an answer for you.

If quote_line_items is a map.resources, then what you want is a `PUT` to `/quote_line_items/:id`
jquery-edit-in-place does a post, but what you want is a put, which you can fake with the _method attribute, so try this url: `'/quote_line_items/90?_method=put'`